# redirection error asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have a problem with my code:

- I would to redirect to an action with arguments from an cshtml file
- but the url is not found
  file Admin cshtml:

  ```
  @{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_General.cshtml";
  }
  <table>
      <tr>
          <td><label  title= "Name " runat="server">Name</label></td>
          <td><label  title= "Email " runat="server">Email</label></td>
          <td><label  title= "Password" runat="server">Password</label></td>
          <td><label  title= "Phone" runat="server">Phone</label></td>
      </tr>

      @foreach (var marker in @Model)
      {
          <tr>
               <td><label  title= "Nom " runat="server" >@marker.ContactName</label>/td>
               <td><label  title= "mail " runat="server">@marker.ContactEmail</label>/td>
               <td><label  title= "mot " runat="server" >@marker.Password</label>/td>
               <td><label  title= "phone " runat="server" >@marker.ContactPhone</label></td>
               <td><label  id="id" style="visibility:hidden">@marker.Identification</label></td>
               <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { Identification = @marker.Identification }) | @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Administration")</td>  
          </tr>
      }
  </table>
  <p>
      @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
  </p>
  ```

my action is this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(string Identification)
{
    DATA2.User u = c.GetUserById(Identification);
    return View(u);
}
```

How can I correct this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that strikes me when looking your code is `runat="server"`. There's no such thing in ASP.NET MVC. Please remove it from every place you have used it.

One problem I can see with your code is the fact the you have decorated your controller action with the `[HttpPost]` attribute. Don't forget that when you define an ActionLink this generates an anchor tag (`<a>`) which in turn sends a GET request to the server. If you decorate your controller action with the `[HttpPost]` attribute you ar ebasically saying that this action can only be invoked with the POST HTTP verb. If you want the action to be accessible from an ActionLink you will have to remove this attribute:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string Identification)
{
    DATA2.User u = c.GetUserById(Identification);
    return View(u);
}
```

Next I guess we have to focus on the Edit link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { Identification = marker.Identification })
```

You are saying that it cannot find the Edit action, am I right? If this is the case then you could also specify the controller action and also the area (if this controller is located inside an area):

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Edit", 
    "Edit", 
    "SomeContorller", 
    new { Identification = "marker.Identification" }, 
    null
)
```

This is necessary if the controller action you are trying to reach is not defined inside the same controller that was used to render the view.